# Printing username using awk command in Unix

Tags: unix, awk

I am new to unix and trying to understand the below awk command:

```
AWK=/bin/awk
RUID=`/usr/bin/id|$AWK -F\( '{print $2}'|$AWK -F\) '{print $1}'`
echo $RUID
```

The command is printing the logged in username, but how the username is extracted using this command.

Comment: `man id` and `man awk` would be a good start

Comment: It's a beautiful `syntax error` on archlinux

Comment: Wow, what a mess, you rarely see so many errors in so few characters! Do NOT try to learn anything about UNIX from whoever wrote that as they are clueless.

Comment: What @EdMorton said. My eyes hurt!

Comment: It reminds me of this old joke: http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/know.your.sysadmin.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command uses the `-F` parameter to split the output from the `id` command by a given character, here `(` in the first and `)` in the second. Not sure if you are familiar with piping?

Using `print $2` then prints the second part, i.e. the part after the first occurrence of `(` and up to the next occurrence. You may see how this works by calling the command manually:

```
/usr/bin/id| $AWK -F\( '{print $2}'
```

This returns `username) gid=1000`.

Then `awk` is called again splitting the string resulting from the first `awk` run on the `)` and then printing the part before the first `)`.

However, the same could be achieved by calling `/usr/bin/id -un` or even simpler `whoami`.

Also try running the `/usr/bin/id` command with no parameters to see the original output that `awk` is parsing here.

Comment: Thanks! Tried to follow the guidelines, as it was my first reply in here. :)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you could try this:

```
whoami
```

If you really want to do it with `awk`:

```
$ id |awk -F'[)(]' '{print $2}'
kent
```

**EDIT**  (for comments)

of course there are other ways to get current login user name/id:

**to get username**

```
kent$  id -un
kent

kent$  echo $USER 
kent

kent$  echo $USERNAME 
kent
```

**to get only UID**

```
kent$  echo $UID 
1000

kent$  id -u
1000
```

Comment: Not me or user2065083, but +1 for justice =)

Comment: @sputnick thx. and good to know that you are an Archer too. :D

Comment: @LynnCrumbling the other answer has already given explanation. And personally, that awk command (in question) is definitely not the right way to go. Therefore I gave two options in my answer. First one is usually what we use in practice, the 2nd one is just for OP's information, using `awk`.  You can keep your downvote, though I think my answer does not deserve it... :( it's ok no problem..

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I didn't get your "better ways to get UID" part. what do you mean by that?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling see the EDIT in answer, do you mean that?

Comment: Backed out my downvote, converted to upvote; like I said, your answer definitely is useful for the OP.